# using @media queries for media compatibility

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I don't believe I'm grasping how to create a responsive website. this is my code:

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: grey;

}
h1{
    color:black;
}

p{
    color:black;
}

@media only screen and(min-width:320px)and(max-width:420px){
    h1{
        color:red;
    }
    p{
        color: white;
    }
}
```

my goal with this small css edit was to see if I understood how the media query worked and to change the h1 and p element colors when a screen size is in-between mobile size.
however, regardless of what size the screen is, there is no changes the elements. I'm slightly confused because I've seen videos of people using this as an example.

Comment: Check this link for more perfection https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Thank you for this resource. (I feel that explaining how I resolved by issue might help someone else resolve theirs in the future)
This helped remember that code is processed top down and I also missed this meta tag 
```<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">```
my issue here I believe was also using min-width and max-width which was resolved  (in my case) by working in decrement from (min-width: 1080) to (min-width: 780) to a (min-width: 420) since I previously built my website for desktop resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right order of things, normals rules first and then mobile rules afterwards.

Let's say you have *two buttons* on the screen for a desktop and a phone. Because a mobile phone obviously does not have the width to spare you may want to show the buttons above and below each other instead of side-by-side.

I have a phone with a horizontal screen width of `375px`. If the buttons are rendered as `250px` then they blatantly won't render side-by-side on my phone without clipping and therefore looking messy to visitors.

Take this code in to consideration:

```
input[type='button'] {display: inline-block; width: calc(50% - 8px);}

@media (max-width: 1024px)
{
 input[type='button'] {width: calc(100% - 8px);}
}
```

The button `input` elements are set to use (roughly) 50% width (compensating a bit for `border` and `margin`). Since they are *inherently* `display: inline;` I'm using `display: inline-block` to keep them rendering on the same line (no line breaks for outright `block`  rendering) though allow setting the `width` hence `inline-block`.

The media queries do *not* negate something like `display` unless it's explicitly defined, again so all the `input` buttons are still rendered as `inline-block`. But now on a mobile screen these buttons will use up enough space that they'll push each other to separate lines.